# Change column value depending on how many times value appears in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Container Event
A         Clean
B         Dry
A         Clean
A         Dry
B         Clean
C         Clean
C         Clean
C         Clean
```

I want to introduce a new column called 'Temperature', which has the value 4 the first time a container has the event 'Clean' and value 3 for all subsequent 'Clean' events. Dry would always have value 1. The dataframe should look like this:

```
Container  Event  Temperature
A          Clean  4
B          Dry    1
A          Clean  3
A          Dry    1
B          Clean  4
C          Clean  4
C          Clean  3
C          Clean  3
```

Reproducible dataframe:

```
d = {'Container': ['A','B','A','A','B','C','C','C'], 'Event': ['Clean', 'Dry', 'Clean', 'Dry', 'Clean', 'Clean', 'Clean', 'Clean']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make conditions and use [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
import numpy as np
cond1 = ~df.duplicated()
cond2 = df['Event'].eq('Clean')
cond3 = df['Event'].eq('Dry')

df['Temperature'] = np.select([cond1 & cond2, cond2, cond3], [4, 3, 1])
```

`df`

```
Container   Event   Temperature
0   A       Clean   4
1   B       Dry     1
2   A       Clean   3
3   A       Dry     1
4   B       Clean   4
5   C       Clean   4
6   C       Clean   3
7   C       Clean   3
```

---

If there are only dry and clean, `cond3` does not need to be created.

```
import numpy as np
cond1 = ~df.duplicated()
cond2 = df['Event'].eq('Clean')

df['Temperature'] = np.select([cond1 & cond2, cond2], [4, 3], 1)
```

same result

Answer (score 2):

one option is with [pyjanitor's case_when](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.case_when.case_when) function:

```py
(df           
.case_when(
    df.Event.eq('Clean') & ~df.duplicated(), 4, #condition, result
    df.Event.eq('Clean'), 3, 
    df.Event.eq('Dry'), 1, 
    column_name = 'Temperature')
)

  Container  Event Temperature
0         A  Clean           4
1         B    Dry           1
2         A  Clean           3
3         A    Dry           1
4         B  Clean           4
5         C  Clean           4
6         C  Clean           3
7         C  Clean           3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can fill in each value in the series for each of the conditions you describe individually:

```
df["Temperature"] = 0
df.loc[(df["Event"] == "Dry").index, "Temperature"] = 1
clean = df[df["Event"] == "Clean"].groupby("Container")["Container"]
df.loc[clean.head(1).index, "Temperature"] = 4
df.loc[clean.tail(-1).index, "Temperature"] = 3
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Container  Event  Temperature
0         A  Clean            4
1         B    Dry            1
2         A  Clean            3
3         A    Dry            1
4         B  Clean            4
5         C  Clean            4
6         C  Clean            3
7         C  Clean            3
```